# warning is given on open google app engine launcher

Tags: google-app-engine

I am newbie.I have successfully installed Google App Engine Launcher.I followed each step clearly which is given here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/308534/google-app-engine-gui-launcher-for-ubuntu-13-04

when i tried to open google app engine launcher, i got following warning

```
$ ./GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py
WARNING:root:
  Warning: Prerequisites for App Engine development are missing!

  A valid python binary must be available.  In addition,
  the App Engine SDK must be installed.  Here are the current
  values we found:

    python = /usr/bin/python
    App Engine SDK root = None

  Please install the missing pieces and restart the launcher.
  If these are installed but the Launcher failed to find them,
  you can configure their location by editing Launcher preferences.

  The Launcher preferences can be modified by selecting Edit > Preferences.
```

Note that i hava already installed Google App Engine SDK for python.

I tried to edit preference in google app engine launcher but i am unable to click on 'edit' option.
Good app engine launcher is not working.

I didn't understand what is going wrong here?.Please help me to fix this warning.

Comment: You might need to include the root of your app engine SDK to your "PATH" variable. Something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\" in your PATH?